# Why is $B=\frac{1}{\omega} k\times E$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, waves, maxwell-equations

Why can we derrive from $B=\frac{k}{\omega}|E|$  the formula  $B=\frac{1}{\omega} k\times E$ ?
Obviously,  because they are perpendicular, but why is it mathematically legitimate?

Comment: It's the other way around. You show that $B = (k \times E)/\omega$ and it is from that and the fact that k and E are perpendicular that the simple scalar relationship is established.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/150188/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation is actually a statement of either Faraday's law or Ampère's law and it only holds for *plane waves*, *i.e.* waves whose field vectors vary with position $\vec{r}$ and time as a vector of the form $\vec{X}\,\exp\left(i\,(\vec{k}\,\cdot\,\vec{r}-\omega\,t)\right)$, where $\vec{X}$ is a constant.

For such a wave, it is not too hard to show that the curl operator becomes $\vec{X}\mapsto i\,\vec{k} \times\vec{X}$ and the divergence $\vec{X}\mapsto i\,\vec{k}\cdot\vec{X}$.

So now, write down Maxwell's equations in freespace, where  $\vec{E}\,\exp\left(i\,(\vec{k}\,\cdot\,\vec{r}-\omega\,t)\right)$ and $\vec{B}\,\exp\left(i\,(\vec{k}\,\cdot\,\vec{r}-\omega\,t)\right)$ are now the assumed electric and magnetic fields; we get:

$$\vec{k}\cdot\vec{E} = \vec{k}\cdot\vec{B} = 0\quad\text{(Gauss's Laws)}$$ 
$$i\,\vec{k}\times\,\vec{E} = i\,\omega\,\vec{B}\quad\text{(Faraday's law)}$$
$$i\,\vec{k}\times\,\vec{B} = -i\,\omega\,\mu_0\,\epsilon_0\,\vec{E}\quad\text{(Ampère's law)}$$

So you recover your statement as Faraday's law, and the only way that Faraday's and Ampère's laws can be consistent is if $|\vec{k}|^2 = \omega^2\,\mu_0\,\epsilon_0$.